# I have installed Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 on live server but unable to integrate payumoney in system/configuration/payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payu, payumoney

I have installed Magento version 1.9.2.4 and as per the [PayUMoney documentation](http://www.webinfosysmailer.in/Magento%20%E2%80%93%20PayUMoney%20Integration.pdf), I have pasted the "payu" folder into respective folder but still not able to see "payucheckout" tab in system/cofiguration/sales/payment method.

Why is this happening?

> "Merge the files and folders in the PayUMoney module with the Magento module. In other words,
>   copy the end files/folders in the integration kit sent to you manually according to the files and folder
>   structure. For e.g.; the payu folder (path - app/code/community/payu) in the integration kit is
>   pasted in the following directory in the Magento folder – ww/magento/app/code/community/."

Answer (score 0):

Merge Payu kit in magento root folder, clear cache and login again,
Enable module from here :

```
 configuration -> payment method -> Payu checkout
```

Payu option will visible on checkout.
For test you can use details in admin: 
Merchant Id: gtKFFx
Salt : eCwWELxi